# How to have two properties in Google Analytics tracking the exact same thing?

Tags: google-analytics, analytics

It's so I can filter one of them to be only 1 campaign specific.

Do I have to install the 2 different codes on my site? They are the same except for the last number of the UA code.

That seems redundant, plus I'm using shopify so there's only one spot to place my UA code.

Answer (score 2):

You don't do this. If you add two GA properties in the page, it should most likely mess up the bounce rates of the GA property that was declared first. What I would use, is setup one property on the page and -

1. Use a segment to track one specific campaign (Campaign name equals the name of the campaign). To do this, in that campaign, I would go about using the [URL Builder tool](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1033867?hl=en)
2. Or, I could define a [new View](https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/1009714?hl=en) (the third column in your admin, besides the property). Where I only include the traffic with the set Campaign name.